# Replace all numerical values in a column into its corresponding state name

Tags: r

I have a column STATE CODE which goes like this:

[image]

You can only see 01 but it goes up to ....53,54,55,56, and 72. See the data dictionary below for all the numbers from 01.

The data set is sorted according to the state codes (01,02,03.....56,72). In the data dictionary, these numbers correspond to state names.

[image]

So in the data dictionary, you can see the numbers represent the states but I want the actual dataset to contain those state names instead of the numbers.

I want the numbers to be replaced by the corresponding state names that they represent according to the data dictionary image.

I could use mutate to replace each number with its corresponding state names but I'm just wondering if there is an easier and more sleek way to do it.

I also wonder if the fact that the states are arranged alphabetically can be used.

To be exact,
this is how it is right now:

```
ST
01
01
01
02
02
04
```

And this is how I want it to be:

```
ST
Alabama     
Alabama 
Alabama                         
Alaska         
Alaska                      
Arizona
```

Here's the text copy of the data dictionary:

```
ST               
State Code
           01 .Alabama/AL                              
           02 .Alaska/AK                               
           04 .Arizona/AZ                              
           05 .Arkansas/AR                             
           06 .California/CA                           
           08 .Colorado/CO                             
           09 .Connecticut/CT                          
           10 .Delaware/DE                             
           11 .District of Columbia/DC                 
           12 .Florida/FL                              
           13 .Georgia/GA                              
           15 .Hawaii/HI                               
           16 .Idaho/ID                                
           17 .Illinois/IL                             
           18 .Indiana/IN                              
           19 .Iowa/IA                                 
           20 .Kansas/KS                               
           21 .Kentucky/KY                             
           22 .Louisiana/LA                            
           23 .Maine/ME                                
           24 .Maryland/MD                             
           25 .Massachusetts/MA                        
           26 .Michigan/MI                             
           27 .Minnesota/MN                            
           28 .Mississippi/MS                          
           29 .Missouri/MO                             
           30 .Montana/MT                              
           31 .Nebraska/NE                             
           32 .Nevada/NV                               
           33 .New Hampshire/NH                        
           34 .New Jersey/NJ                           
           35 .New Mexico/NM                           
           36 .New York/NY                             
           37 .North Carolina/NC                       
           38 .North Dakota/ND
           39 .Ohio/OH                                 
           40 .Oklahoma/OK                             
           41 .Oregon/OR                               
           42 .Pennsylvania/PA                         
           44 .Rhode Island/RI                         
           45 .South Carolina/SC                       
           46 .South Dakota/SD                         
           47 .Tennessee/TN                            
           48 .Texas/TX                                
           49 .Utah/UT                                 
           50 .Vermont/VT                              
           51 .Virginia/VA                             
           53 .Washington/WA                           
           54 .West Virginia/WV                        
           55 .Wisconsin/WI                            
           56 .Wyoming/WY                              
           72 .Puerto Rico/PR
```

I have tried doing mutate and it worked, but I don't want to do mutate for every single code.

EDIT:

Imported the text file with the list of states into R and made it into a dataset using @akrun's code.

[image]

As you can see it has taken Alabama as a heading.

The following is the text file I used:

[image]

Please advise what changes I can make to

1. Fix the heading so that Alabama goes down a cell to look like this:

```
State Code   State Name
1            Alabama
2            Alaska
```

I also wonder how can I remove every word after the "/" in the column values.

So for example, in the following screenshot:

[image]

I would rather it be just Alaska instead of Alaska/AK.

**EDIT2:**

I combined a bunch of code and after trying them all, this was the code that worked best for my question:

```
df <- structure(list(`state code` = c("01", "02", "04", "05", "06", 
                                  "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", 
                                  "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", 
                                  "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", 
                                  "42", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "53", "54", 
                                  "55", "56", "72"), state = c("Alabama/AL", "Alaska/AK", "Arizona/AZ", 
                                                               "Arkansas/AR", "California/CA", "Colorado/CO", "Connecticut/CT", 
                                                               "Delaware/DE", "District of Columbia/DC", "Florida/FL", "Georgia/GA", 
                                                               "Hawaii/HI", "Idaho/ID", "Illinois/IL", "Indiana/IN", "Iowa/IA", 
                                                               "Kansas/KS", "Kentucky/KY", "Louisiana/LA", "Maine/ME", "Maryland/MD", 
                                                               "Massachusetts/MA", "Michigan/MI", "Minnesota/MN", "Mississippi/MS", 
                                                               "Missouri/MO", "Montana/MT", "Nebraska/NE", "Nevada/NV", 
                                                               "New Hampshire/NH", "New Jersey/NJ", "New Mexico/NM", "New York/NY", 
                                                               "North Carolina/NC", "North Dakota/ND", "Ohio/OH", "Oklahoma/OK", 
                                                               "Oregon/OR", "Pennsylvania/PA", "Rhode Island/RI", "South Carolina/SC", 
                                                               "South Dakota/SD", "Tennessee/TN", "Texas/TX", "Utah/UT", 
                                                               "Vermont/VT", "Virginia/VA", "Washington/WA", "West Virginia/WV", 
                                                               "Wisconsin/WI", "Wyoming/WY", "Puerto Rico/PR")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                  -52L), class = "data.frame")

st <- structure(list(ST = c("01", "02", "04", "05", "06","08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", 
                            "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", 
                            "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", 
                            "42", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "53", "54", 
                            "55", "56", "72")), 
                row.names = c(NA,-52L), class = "data.frame")

    df2 <- data.frame(ST = gsub("/.*|\\W", "", lapply(st$ST, function(x) 
      df[x == df$'state code',2])))
    
    st$df2 <- df2
    
    st
    
    names(st) <- c("State Code", "State Names")
```

Running that code gives me the following result:

[Result of above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fv4qM.png)

But I am not able to change the column name to remove the $ST from after State Names.

My code `names(st) <- c("State Code", "State Names")` should change the name to make it normal - State Names - but it doesn't work for some reason.

Any advice on that would be helpful.

Comment: Can you please state how your data looks like in R with `dput(head(data))` and delete all other screenshots!

Comment: @AndreWildberg , after applying `dput(head(st))` to the edit2 result,
this is what the result is:
structure(list(`State Code` = c("01", "02", "04", "05", "06", 
"08"), `State Names` = structure(list(ST = c("Alabama", "Alaska", 
"Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

Answer (score 1):

You can use `recode` to obtain the desired output, you just need do some cleaning on the data dictionary.

```
library(tidyverse)

df1<-tibble(ST=c("01","01","02","04","04","04","05"))
df2<-read.csv(text=c("State Code
01. Alabama/AL
02. Alaska/AK
04. Arizona/AZ
05. Arkansas/AR"),sep="",colClasses = c("character", "character"))

df2 <- df2 |>
  # remove extra point
  mutate(across(State, ~str_replace(.x, "\\.", ""))) |>
  # Extract only the name of the state
  mutate(across(Code, ~str_extract(.x, "^[A-z]+(?=\\/)"))) 

df1 |>
  mutate(ST_new = recode(df1$ST, !!!deframe(df2)))

# A tibble: 7 × 2
#  ST    ST_new  
#  <chr> <chr>   
#1 01    Alabama 
#2 01    Alabama 
#3 02    Alaska  
#4 04    Arizona 
#5 04    Arizona 
#6 04    Arizona 
#7 05    Arkansas
```

Answer (score 0):

We may read read the dictionary with `readLines`, replace the first space with `,`, then read with `read.csv` to create a data.frame, do a join with the first dataset

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
str_replace(trimws(lines[-1]), " ", ",") %>% 
  read.csv(text = ., header = TRUE, colClasses = "character") %>% 
  left_join(df1, ., by = c("ST" = "State")) %>%
  transmute(ST = str_replace(Code, "^\\.?([^/]+)/.*", "\\1"))
```

-output

```
    ST
1 Alabama
2 Alabama
3 Alabama
4  Alaska
5  Alaska
6 Arizona
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ST = c("01", "01", "01", "02", "02", "04")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")

lines <- readLines("file.txt")
```

Comment: There is no df2.. The list of state names is just text.

Comment: @Annie Are you reading the file with `read.table` or `readLines`

Comment: So the original dataset is from a csv file. So I used read_csv.

Comment: The list with the state names is just a text file. I'm not reading and I don't know how to convert the text into an r dataset.

Comment: @Annie what about the first file.  Is it a data.frame?  Does it have string values as `01`, `02` etc or just `1`, `2` after reading

Comment: The first file is a csv file converted to a dataframe, yes. After reading it is <chr> so I think it is string values.

Comment: @Annie Have you tried reading the second data as `read.table("yourfile.txt", header = TRUE, skip = 1)`

Comment: I used your code and made the text into a dataset in R but there are some issues. Can you please check the post for the edit? I have added an image there for clarification.

Comment: @Annie Can you try the update

Comment: I have uploaded the results of your code now.

Comment: @Annie maybe there are some spaces in your text.  Try the update

Comment: made some changes, pls check EDIT2. Thanks!